# How could I refresh the frame of Qt 3D?

Tags: qt3d

there is a big problem about the newest Qt 3D API: after I updated to the Qt Creator 4.7.2, the original 3D scence does not refresh until I drag the whole window around. The frame is just stuck.

Comment: Please add a [minimally working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people can follow what you are talking about. What Qt version are you using? Qt3D refreshes aromatically unless you tell it to do otherwise.